# Error in velocity and log4J

Tags: java, servlets, log4j, stack-trace, velocity

I built a webapp that works perfectly fine in my localhost (tomcat). But when I tried to deploy, velocity crashes in init(), leaving me with this strange stack trace here (sorry for the size):

```
ERROR [main] (VelocityConfigurator.java:62) - Error initializing Velocity!
org.apache.velocity.exception.VelocityException: Failed to initialize an instance of org.apache.velocity.runtime.log.Log4JLogChute with the current runtime configuration.
    at org.apache.velocity.runtime.log.LogManager.createLogChute(LogManager.java:206)
    at org.apache.velocity.runtime.log.LogManager.updateLog(LogManager.java:255)
    at org.apache.velocity.runtime.RuntimeInstance.initializeLog(RuntimeInstance.java:795)
    at org.apache.velocity.runtime.RuntimeInstance.init(RuntimeInstance.java:250)
    at org.apache.velocity.runtime.RuntimeInstance.init(RuntimeInstance.java:589)
    at org.apache.velocity.runtime.RuntimeSingleton.init(RuntimeSingleton.java:229)
    at org.apache.velocity.app.Velocity.init(Velocity.java:107)
    at com.webcodei.velociraptor.velocity.VelocityConfigurator.initVelocity(VelocityConfigurator.java:57)
    at com.webcodei.velociraptor.velocity.VelocityConfigurator.configure(VelocityConfigurator.java:42)
    at com.webcodei.velociraptor.VelociListener.contextInitialized(VelociListener.java:26)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:3827)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4336)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:761)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:741)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:525)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:626)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptors(HostConfig.java:553)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:488)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1138)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:311)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:120)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1023)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:719)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1015)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:443)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:448)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:710)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:552)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:288)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:413)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error configuring Log4JLogChute : 
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
    at org.apache.velocity.util.ExceptionUtils.createWithCause(ExceptionUtils.java:67)
    at org.apache.velocity.util.ExceptionUtils.createRuntimeException(ExceptionUtils.java:45)
    at org.apache.velocity.runtime.log.Log4JLogChute.initAppender(Log4JLogChute.java:133)
    at org.apache.velocity.runtime.log.Log4JLogChute.init(Log4JLogChute.java:85)
    at org.apache.velocity.runtime.log.LogManager.createLogChute(LogManager.java:157)
    ... 33 more
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: velocity.log (Permission denied)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.openAppend(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.(FileOutputStream.java:177)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.(FileOutputStream.java:102)
    at org.apache.log4j.FileAppender.setFile(FileAppender.java:290)
    at org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender.setFile(RollingFileAppender.java:194)
    at org.apache.log4j.FileAppender.(FileAppender.java:109)
    at org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender.(RollingFileAppender.java:72)
    at org.apache.velocity.runtime.log.Log4JLogChute.initAppender(Log4JLogChute.java:118)
    ... 35 more
ERROR [main] (VelocityConfigurator.java:63) - java.lang.RuntimeException: Error configuring Log4JLogChute : 
org.apache.velocity.exception.VelocityException: Failed to initialize an instance of org.apache.velocity.runtime.log.Log4JLogChute with the current runtime configuration.
    at org.apache.velocity.runtime.log.LogManager.createLogChute(LogManager.java:206)
    at org.apache.velocity.runtime.log.LogManager.updateLog(LogManager.java:255)
    at org.apache.velocity.runtime.RuntimeInstance.initializeLog(RuntimeInstance.java:795)
    at org.apache.velocity.runtime.RuntimeInstance.init(RuntimeInstance.java:250)
    at org.apache.velocity.runtime.RuntimeInstance.init(RuntimeInstance.java:589)
    at org.apache.velocity.runtime.RuntimeSingleton.init(RuntimeSingleton.java:229)
    at org.apache.velocity.app.Velocity.init(Velocity.java:107)
    at com.webcodei.velociraptor.velocity.VelocityConfigurator.initVelocity(VelocityConfigurator.java:57)
    at com.webcodei.velociraptor.velocity.VelocityConfigurator.configure(VelocityConfigurator.java:42)
    at com.webcodei.velociraptor.VelociListener.contextInitialized(VelociListener.java:26)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:3827)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4336)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:761)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:741)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:525)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:626)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptors(HostConfig.java:553)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:488)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1138)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:311)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:120)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1023)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:719)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1015)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:443)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:448)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:710)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:552)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:288)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:413)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error configuring Log4JLogChute : 
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
    at org.apache.velocity.util.ExceptionUtils.createWithCause(ExceptionUtils.java:67)
    at org.apache.velocity.util.ExceptionUtils.createRuntimeException(ExceptionUtils.java:45)
    at org.apache.velocity.runtime.log.Log4JLogChute.initAppender(Log4JLogChute.java:133)
    at org.apache.velocity.runtime.log.Log4JLogChute.init(Log4JLogChute.java:85)
    at org.apache.velocity.runtime.log.LogManager.createLogChute(LogManager.java:157)
    ... 33 more
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: velocity.log (Permission denied)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.openAppend(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.(FileOutputStream.java:177)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.(FileOutputStream.java:102)
    at org.apache.log4j.FileAppender.setFile(FileAppender.java:290)
    at org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender.setFile(RollingFileAppender.java:194)
    at org.apache.log4j.FileAppender.(FileAppender.java:109)
    at org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender.(RollingFileAppender.java:72)
    at org.apache.velocity.runtime.log.Log4JLogChute.initAppender(Log4JLogChute.java:118)
    ... 35 more
ERROR [main] (VelocityConfigurator.java:64) - Failed to initialize an instance of org.apache.velocity.runtime.log.Log4JLogChute with the current runtime configuration.
org.apache.velocity.exception.VelocityException: Failed to initialize an instance of org.apache.velocity.runtime.log.Log4JLogChute with the current runtime configuration.
    at org.apache.velocity.runtime.log.LogManager.createLogChute(LogManager.java:206)
    at org.apache.velocity.runtime.log.LogManager.updateLog(LogManager.java:255)
    at org.apache.velocity.runtime.RuntimeInstance.initializeLog(RuntimeInstance.java:795)
    at org.apache.velocity.runtime.RuntimeInstance.init(RuntimeInstance.java:250)
    at org.apache.velocity.runtime.RuntimeInstance.init(RuntimeInstance.java:589)
    at org.apache.velocity.runtime.RuntimeSingleton.init(RuntimeSingleton.java:229)
    at org.apache.velocity.app.Velocity.init(Velocity.java:107)
    at com.webcodei.velociraptor.velocity.VelocityConfigurator.initVelocity(VelocityConfigurator.java:57)
    at com.webcodei.velociraptor.velocity.VelocityConfigurator.configure(VelocityConfigurator.java:42)
    at com.webcodei.velociraptor.VelociListener.contextInitialized(VelociListener.java:26)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:3827)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4336)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:761)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:741)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:525)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:626)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptors(HostConfig.java:553)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:488)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1138)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:311)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:120)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1023)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:719)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1015)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:443)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:448)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:710)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:552)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:288)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:413)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error configuring Log4JLogChute : 
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
    at org.apache.velocity.util.ExceptionUtils.createWithCause(ExceptionUtils.java:67)
    at org.apache.velocity.util.ExceptionUtils.createRuntimeException(ExceptionUtils.java:45)
    at org.apache.velocity.runtime.log.Log4JLogChute.initAppender(Log4JLogChute.java:133)
    at org.apache.velocity.runtime.log.Log4JLogChute.init(Log4JLogChute.java:85)
    at org.apache.velocity.runtime.log.LogManager.createLogChute(LogManager.java:157)
    ... 33 more
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: velocity.log (Permission denied)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.openAppend(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.(FileOutputStream.java:177)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.(FileOutputStream.java:102)
    at org.apache.log4j.FileAppender.setFile(FileAppender.java:290)
    at org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender.setFile(RollingFileAppender.java:194)
    at org.apache.log4j.FileAppender.(FileAppender.java:109)
    at org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender.(RollingFileAppender.java:72)
    at org.apache.velocity.runtime.log.Log4JLogChute.initAppender(Log4JLogChute.java:118)
    ... 35 more
```

Does anyone knows the workaround? Or at least understood the error? I've done some googling but no clues.. only this [page](http://www.nabble.com/org.apache.velocity.runtime.log.Log4JLogChute-initialization-failed-td22099662.html) facing the same problem but no solution..

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think this line has the answer.  Looks like there is an issue creating the velocity.log file.  What does your configuration file look like?

```
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: velocity.log (Permission denied)
```

Comment: It was exactly that, I will put the work around when I have time.

Comment: I have the same problem.  Where is it trying to create the velocity.log file?  What directory?

Comment: I had this problem too. Mine was because file was owned by root instead of webserver user.  I ended up doing cd /; find -name "velocity.log".  Then once I found it: chown <user>:<group> velocity.log

Comment: Where you created this file manually @Brucewayne-TheGeekKiller

Comment: that will depend upon what application u have, i had the above problem when i worked with kylo.  I created `velocity.log` manually on path `/home/kylo` @rinilnath So inshort, if it is telling permission denied, it could be either permission issue or otherwise file itself won't be there

Comment: I managed the file path via a code like 
 ve.setProperty("runtime.log", "C:\\mypath\\velocity.log"),
But do you know how to make this achieve through property file ?, I know the key to place in property file , but how to make the property file active ?

Answer (score 40):

Velocity tries to put the logfile in the directory Tomcat was started from, and I believe that is actually /.

You can force Velocity to log to Tomcat's standard log by adding these lines to your velocity.properties:

```
runtime.log.logsystem.class=org.apache.velocity.runtime.log.SimpleLog4JLogSystem
runtime.log.logsystem.log4j.category=velocity
runtime.log.logsystem.log4j.logger=velocity
```

The velocity.properties should go into /WEB-INF/velocity.properties but you can override that in you servlet definition in web.xml.

If you're initialising Velocity by properties and not the velocity.properties:

```
VelocityEngine engine = new VelocityEngine();

Properties props = new Properties();
props.put("runtime.log.logsystem.class", "org.apache.velocity.runtime.log.SimpleLog4JLogSystem");
props.put("runtime.log.logsystem.log4j.category", "velocity");
props.put("runtime.log.logsystem.log4j.logger", "velocity");

engine.init(props);
```

Read more here:

http://velocity.apache.org/engine/devel/developer-guide.html#usinglog4jwithexistinglogger

and here:

http://minaret.biz/tips/tomcatLogging.html#velocity

Comment: recently, the recommended SimpleLog4JLogSystem seems to be deprecated, so the class [Log4JLogChute](http://velocity.apache.org/engine/devel/apidocs/org/apache/velocity/runtime/log/Log4JLogChute.html) should be used instead. Also, if you do not want to tie your application to log4j directly, [Slf4jLogChute](http://velocity.apache.org/engine/devel/apidocs/org/apache/velocity/slf4j/Slf4jLogChute.html) might be a reasonable alternative.

Comment: How to make the application take from the velocity.properties file, i have given some settings in properties file but it does not seem to be picked up

Comment: It seems my `velocity.properties` was always ignored. Therefore I edited the `org/apache/velocity/runtime/defaults/velocity.properties` directly in the jar and defined `runtime.log.logsystem.class = org.apache.velocity.runtime.log.NullLogChute`.
It is absolutely not a beautiful solution, but it works in my case.

Answer (score 4):

It appears the process attempting to open the log file does not have permission to do so:

```
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: velocity.log (Permission denied)
```

Answer (score 1):

I too had same Issue but I was able to resolve this overriding the default log file to customized log file. Just add this 3 lines of code in the method where you are calling evaluate Function.

```
Velocity.setProperty(RuntimeConstants.RUNTIME_LOG_LOGSYSTEM_CLASS,"org.apache.velocity.runtime.log.Log4JLogChute");

Velocity.setProperty("runtime.log.logsystem.log4j.logger","com.mindtree.igg.website.email.TemplateMergeUtilVelocityImpl");

VelocityContext velocityContext = new VelocityContext(parameters);
```

This is one way of solving it ie, without using property file.

Answer (score 1):

I have had exactly the same problem with my code and after hours of googling for that , I just decided to add some other Velocity libraries to my project.
My project only had the apache-velocity jar file, then from [here](http://mvnrepository.com/search?q=velocity), I also added Velocity-Dep to my Maven project and Yesssssssssss! VICTORY!