# Email sending working in locally but not working in aws

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I have a java application with email sending service.
Domain i set in Godaddy. In godaddy only we have office 365 account.
Email sending is working fine in locally. But when i hosted in AWS ec2 ubuntu instance Emails are not being sent. Do i need to do any configuration in AWS.
Thanks in advance.
     **I am getting error in console as Exception: Velocity could not be         Initialized.**

Comment: Is your EC2 on a private subnet?

Comment: sorry i am not aware about subnet Terminology. I am a developer i am working on aws free basic account. Is this problem related to subnet means please provide me any related information.@Ashan

Comment: You could try checking the Security Group's allowed ports and comparing them to what your email sending service wants to use. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/authorizing-access-to-an-instance.html

Comment: office 365 is using Port 587 i already open even though not working. I am getting error in console as Exception: Velocity could not be Initialized.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution the main cause is velocity.log file was not able to create due to permission issues in AWS. TO create that log messages in tomcat log its self i updated this code

```
VelocityEngine engine = new VelocityEngine();

Properties props = new Properties();
props.put("runtime.log.logsystem.class","org.apache.velocity.runtime.log.SimpleLog4JLogSystem");
props.put("runtime.log.logsystem.log4j.category", "velocity");
props.put("runtime.log.logsystem.log4j.logger", "velocity");
```

For more information check this link
[Error in velocity and log4J](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/849710/error-in-velocity-and-log4j)